# Point-convolution in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I would like to implement a point-convolution to my input tensor.

Let's say we have:

```
input_ = torch.randn(1,1,8,1)

input_.shape
Out[70]: torch.Size([1, 1, 8, 1])

input_
Out[71]: 
tensor([[[[ 0.7656],
          [-0.3400],
          [-0.2487],
          [ 0.6246],
          [ 2.0450],
          [-0.9588],
          [ 1.2221],
          [-1.3164]]]])
```

where the dimensions represent respectively `(batch_size, n_channels, height, width)`.
Then, (keeping fixed batch_size and channel), I would like to apply to each a `nn.Conv1d` layer basically to expand the number of channels. What I've tried has been:

```
list(torch.unbind(input_,dim=2))
Out[72]: 
[tensor([[[0.7656]]]),
 tensor([[[-0.3400]]]),
 tensor([[[-0.2487]]]),
 tensor([[[0.6246]]]),
 tensor([[[2.0450]]]),
 tensor([[[-0.9588]]]),
 tensor([[[1.2221]]]),
 tensor([[[-1.3164]]])]
```

and then applying `nn.Conv1d` entrywise to these elements? Would that be a correct way?

EDIT:

Should I use nn.Conv1d directly on my original input_ by doing

```
conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=3, kernel_size=(1,1)

conv(input_)

conv(input_)
Out[89]: 
tensor([[[[-0.1481],
          [ 1.5345],
          [ 0.3082],
          [ 1.8677],
          [ 0.7515],
          [ 1.2916],
          [ 0.0218],
          [ 0.5606]],

         [[-1.2975],
          [-0.3080],
          [-1.0292],
          [-0.1121],
          [-0.7685],
          [-0.4509],
          [-1.1976],
          [-0.8808]],

         [[-0.7169],
          [ 0.6493],
          [-0.3464],
          [ 0.9199],
          [ 0.0135],
          [ 0.4521],
          [-0.5790],
          [-0.1415]]]], grad_fn=<ThnnConv2DBackward0>)

conv(input_).shape
Out[90]: torch.Size([1, 3, 8, 1])
```

I'm not sure though if doing this is the same as my original purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by "point-convolution"?

Comment: just a 1d convolution using a kernel of shape (1,1).

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is what you are accomplishing..